# Как получить название всех папок на диске?

Tags: c#, файловая-система

Имеется следующий код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
            foreach (string d in Drives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);

                string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
                Console.WriteLine(files);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Название существующих дисков он выводит правильно, но как только дело доходит до названия папок, он выводит

```
System.string[]
```

Если не имеет на себе файлов, то возникает исключение

```
System.IO.IOException: "Устройство не готово".
```

Как можно получить имена всех папок (не считая вложенных), расположенных на диске (если они есть), в противном случае пропустить исключение и продолжить работу программы.

Comment: Имеется некоторая неоднозначность в вашем вопросе. Логический раздел диска может быть примонтирован как папка на другом разделе, иметь более одной назначенной буквы, как логический раздел будет определяться примонтированный сетевой диск. В остальном `try ... catch` вам в помощь, он специально предназначен для работы с исключениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Диск: {d} пуст");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как обработать исключение "System.IO.IOException: "Устройство не готово."?
Такое возникает с диском, который не содержит файлов, например, пустой дисковод.

Comment: На какой строке выбрасывает исключение?

Comment: string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(d);

Comment: Подправил ответ